# How can we send response from azure logic app to Power bi for generating insights if response is true?

Tags: powerbi, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to send output of my response from Azure logic app withhttptriggerto Power bi data source and generate visuals whenever there is a positive or negative response from my logic app design flow.
What data source can I select in Power bi desktop version?
Is there API which can be used for same purpose? If yes, please provide the API details as well.

I tried to do it in online version but I need to do it for desktop version of Power bi

Comment: What data is your logicapp generating? The logicapp must be getting data from another source or something because it’s not typically a mechanism for generating a data set. Can you clarify WHERE data in the logicapp is coming from?

Comment: The data generated is based upon the trigger from data factory alert. It is trying to check certain condition and based upon that it is generating a response with a statement. So if the condition was true I want to generate a positive spike in the visual else 0.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever there is a positive or negative response from my logic app design flow.

You can use a [condition connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement) placed before to perform this requirement

[image]

> What data source can I select in Power bi desktop version?

There is no direct connector that may help you to generate reports but there is a vast area from where you can send the data to particular storage and generate the reports from there. For Example, you can save your data to Azure blob storage through logic apps and then get the data from Azure blob storage to generate reports from power bi. Below are all the ways where we can get the data to generate reports.

[image]

The present [power bi Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerbi/) in the logic app may help you to Use Power BI REST API to add rows to a dataset, Use Power BI Rest API to initiate export for Power BI reports, and other few actions. But there is always an option to do our own custom connector for power bi from logic apps through Custom connectors.

For more information regarding this, you can refer [Create a Custom Connector for Logic Apps using the Azure portal - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/create-a-custom-connector-for-logic-apps-using-the-azure-portal/ba-p/2887879#:%7E:text=%20Steps%3A%20%201%20First%20youll%20need%20to,Portal%20select%20%22Create%20a%20resource%22%20and...%20More%20)

Here is a [tutorial](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/industry-blog/en-gb/technetuk/2021/04/08/using-power-bi-and-logic-apps-to-analyse-social-media-streams/#:%7E:text=LogicApp%20is%20used%20to%20pull%20the%20data%20from,to%20generate%20aggregates/measures/KPIs%20and%20to%20visualise%20the%20data.) where data is sent to the Azure SQL Database and the reports will be generated from Azure SQL Database.